# Subplots not populating correctly

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to use Pandas DataFrame.plot() to plot two variable bar plots side by side with the following code:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax1 = train_df['Condition1'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
ax2 = train_df['Condition2'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

The result is this:

[image]

The data is Kaggle's House Prices dataset, however I do not think it matters to answering the question. I have tried this with multiple pairs of variables just to be sure. It only ever shows one plot on the right.

Interestingly enough, the assignment of axes does not matter. If you only assign `ax1`, it will show in the right hand plot. If you only assign `ax2`, it will be on the right side.

This occurs no matter what orientation I choose for my subplots (2,) (1,2), (2,1). Always one empty plot.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already created the axes with your first line of code. Your second and third code line overwrite these.

You need to pass `ax1` and `ax2` as arguments to pandas' plot function instead.

Try this:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
train_df['Condition1'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', ax=ax1)
train_df['Condition2'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. However, I'm looking at the docs for Series.plot() and see no mention of the `ax` argument. It must be one of the matplotlib **kwargs.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad that you could solve it. I quickly checked the docs as well. I reckon too that the `ax` arguments is one of the kwargs.